# Error when starting a hive thrift server on EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive

In the following code I'm trying to start a hive thrift server from spark:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HiveDemo")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sql = new HiveContext(sc)

sql.setConf("hive.server2.thrift.port", "10001")

val df = sql.read.parquet("s3n://...")
df.registerTempTable("test")

HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(sql)

while (true) {
  Thread.`yield`()
}
```

And I'm running this code as a step on an EMR cluster with the following configs:

```
emr-4.6.0
spark 1.6.1
hive 1.0.0
```

And I'm attaching to the cluster to test if the table is created with beeline using:

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001
```

I get **Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused**

Is there an additional setup step that I'm missing on EMR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this problem is fixed in Hive [1.3.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE/fixforversion/12332154) and [2.0.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE/fixforversion/12332641). So upgrade your version.

This problem occurs because [Beeline's use of failed connection(s) causes failures and leaks.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12517). All(`error reproducing, how it is solved and which versions are containing the fix`) are included in this link.

Hope it will help you.

### UPDATE1:

**is your hive Server is running in HTTP mode?**

Connection URL When `HiveServer2` Is Running in HTTP Mode:-

```
jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>;transportMode=http;httpPath=<http_endpoint>
```

where:-

`<http_endpoint>` is the corresponding HTTP endpoint configured in `hive-site.xml`. Default value is cliservice.

Default port for HTTP transport mode is 10001.

### Resource Link:

1. [Hive Client Details](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient)
2. [Hive JDBC : Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/9066/hive-jdbc-could-not-open-client-transport-with-jdb.html)

Comment: Amazon is using it's own version of Hive, and the latest version is 1.0.0. How it is possible to upgrade that?

Comment: @djWann is your hive Server is running in HTTP mode?

Comment: @djWann I have updated answer. Please have a look in updated section.